# Custom components in JavaFX Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have a project written in JavaFX 8 and want to use Scene Builder 2 for GUI adaptions.
There are a couple of custom components used within the views, which are located in JAR files.
Now I know that I can import a JAR, but I have to do it each time I open Scene Builder.
Isn't there a way to make the custom components available to Scene Builder once and forever?

Comment: Can you explain how you are importing the jar files? Components in jar files I import into the library are available under "Custom" next time I start SceneBuilder. (I am using SceneBuilder 8, but if I remember correctly the same thing was available in SceneBuilder 2.) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0

Comment: @James_D Mmm, you are right - so I have to check why Scene Builder is still complaining when opening the view. What do you mean by "Scene Builder 8"? I thought Scene Builder 2.0 is the current version?

Comment: Oracle is no longer developing SceneBuilder: it has been released as open source. The development is now lead by Gluon, and the latest version (8.0.0) is available [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). Note that this will not integrate (yet) with IDEs (at least without some hackery).