# JavaFX all component in loop

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want cut my code in fxml.

```
fx1.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
    doThis();
});
fx2.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
    doThis();
});
fx3.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
    doThis();
});
fx4.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
    doThis();
});
fx5.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
    doThis();
});
```

I want loop in this component. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an all-Java application (or if these controls are created in Java), you can simply create them in a loop and register the listener when you create them:

```
for (int i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    TextField fx = new TextField();
    fx.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> doThis());
    somePane.getChildren().add(fx);
}
```

If these are FXML-injected, they need their own identity. The shortest code is probably to create a stream:

```
Stream.of(fx1, fx2, fx3, fx4, fx5)
    .map(TextField::textProperty)
    .forEach(text -> text.addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> doThis()));
```

Also see [adding elements defined in FXML to list with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309993/adding-elements-defined-in-fxml-to-list-with-loop)