# FXML - multiple custom type objects defined in .fxml file

Tags: java, fxml

My main UI is defined in an FXML file and is supposed to contain a list of persons.
A person would have a picture and some different lines of read-only text to display (name, age, etc...)
The list itself will change all the time throughout runtime. (CRUD)

I know it would be possible to create a person-class and just add instances of it to a VBox/Hbox/... at runtime *but* I would like to create the definition of what the person should look like in an FXML file - if possible.

Is there a way to do this AND also fill these 'object-templates' with data (picture and texts) like with a normal template via the @FXML annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html) tool to create *fxml* files. With SceneBuilder, you can create custom FXML elements, and embed them to each other.
Check these links out:

https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/adding-custom-javafx-components-to-scene-builder-2-0/

[Adding a custom component to SceneBuilder 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0)