# JavaFX - Button which contains a Double

Tags: javafx

I have a button that adds its name to a TextArea. I want the button to hold a double that also gets displayed in the text area but is not displayed on the button itself.

Here is my MainMenuController where the TextArea is

```
@FXML TextArea txtReceipt;

@FXML
public void buttonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    txtReceipt.appendText ((String) button.getText() + "\n");
}
```

At first, I extended the Button class to include a double. However, JavaFX does not recognize this as a control. 
I then made a class to hold a button to no avail.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;


/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class NumButton extends Button{

    double cost;



   private void setCost(double cost)
   {
       this.cost = cost;
   }

}
```

Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?
I am thinking that perhaps

```
Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
txtReceipt.appendText ((String) button.getText() + "\n");
```

should be

```
NumButton numButton = (Button) event.getSource();
txtReceipt.appendText ((String) numButton.getText() + numButton.cost + "\n");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "At first, I extended the Button class to include a double. However, JavaFX does not recognize this as a control."? A subclass of `Button` will also be a subclass of `Control`, since `Button` is a subclass of `Control`.

Comment: JavaFx interface does not see NumButton when I try to add it.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean by that. If you make `NumButton` a subclass of `Button`, you can use `NumButton` anywhere you can use a `Button`. What do you mean by "JavaFX interface does not see `NumButton`"? What interface?

Comment: Scenebuilder 2.0. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I didn't realize you were using SceneBuilder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0 (You should also consider upgrading to a more [recent version](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).)

Comment: Thx James! Much appreciated