# How to have images overlap each other in a VBox

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am using Scene Builder to create my scenes, I have added cards (ImageViews) to the VBoxes and all 12 cards don't seem to nicely fit, although they do fit in the HBoxes that I have. I couldn't find any property that lets me reduce the spacing between Nodes inside my VBox. I have shown a picture of how my VBox looks and there is also a picture of my HBox (thats how I want it to look). If that's not possible then I want to be able to overlap the images so they do fit.

[image: Vbox]

[image: Hbox]

Comment: Either your VBox has a spacing property set to a non-zero value or your images have a little transparent region on the top. Can you please check?

Comment: actually originally the images were being added straight like they are in the HBox, so I rotated the images so they face the center which caused the extra space. Either way, I wasn't able to show 12 images like the HBox shows them.

Comment: You can make use of the [viewportProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty--) to define specific area to use from your ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by `VBox` (At least there is no way I know of that would).

You could however override `layoutChildren` to move up the nodes, if the content does not fit and override `computeMinHeight` to return the maximum of the minHeight values:

```
public class OverlappingVBox extends VBox {

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        List<Node> managed = getManagedChildren();

        int count = managed.size();
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        double contentAreaMaxY = getHeight() - getInsets().getBottom();

        Node lastNode = managed.get(managed.size() - 1);
        double maxY = lastNode.getLayoutY() + lastNode.getLayoutBounds().getMaxY();

        if (contentAreaMaxY < maxY) {
            // reduce layoutY if content does not fit
            double gap = (contentAreaMaxY - maxY) / (count - 1);
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                Node n = managed.get(i);
                n.setLayoutY(n.getLayoutY() + i * gap);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMinHeight(double width) {
        // min height = max min height
        double result = 0;
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        double contentWidth = width - insets.getLeft() - insets.getRight();
        for (Node n : getManagedChildren()) {
            double mH = n.minHeight(contentWidth);
            if (mH > result) {
                result = mH;
            }
        }
        return result + insets.getTop() + insets.getBottom();
    }

}
```

#### Usage example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    OverlappingVBox root = new OverlappingVBox();

    Color c = Color.WHITE;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        root.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(50, 50, c));
        c = c.invert();
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: how would I use this keeping in mind that I used the scene builder to create my Vbox, which is inside a BoarderPane. Can I create an OverlappingVbox object and set it to my Vbox through casting?

Comment: You should be able to use `OverlappingVBox` instead of `VBox` by replacing `<VBox>` elements with `<OverlappingVBox>` elements (be sure the appropriate `<?import ?>` processing instruction is added). Since `OverlappingVBox` extends `VBox` an assignment of a `OverlappingVBox` to a `VBox` field works fine. `FXMLLoader` also has no difficulties to inject the node to a field... You could also add the layout to scenebuilder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0

Comment: this solves most of my problem, but the 1st card is still not visible (half covered) while there is still space at the bottom

Comment: @ScrappyMontana Whoops, there was a typo `maxY` needs to be calculated `maxY` not `maxX` of course...