# Creating objects of user defined classes with scene builder and javafx

Tags: class, object, javafx, scenebuilder, user-event

I'm facing a really disturbing problem. I'm working on a simple chess project game using javafx and scene builder. I have created the board (without pieces) as 8×8 gridpane then I added 64 square with black and white colord as in chess board. All of the previous was done in using fxml file and a controller plus a main javafx class. Now I created a class for the knight so I can add the methods of its moves and apply oop concepts with this project. I want to create an istance of the class knight. and as it's  javafx project I created it the instance in the controller class but I faced the following two problems.

1_ the knight is originally an imageview in the scene builder so I can't assign the name of the new created instance with scene builder.

2- how do I call those methods.so they are used to handle user events.

I'm not that fimilar with javafx so I haven't tried alot. I hope someone can guide me.
put into consideration that this a learning project mostly focusing on building strong logic , diving deep with oop plus having some knowledge about javafx .

Comment: I don’t really understand what you’re asking here. (For example: what does *” I can't assign the name of the new created instance with scene builder”* mean?). However, if the question is just how to use your own classes in SceneBuilder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0

Comment: "simple chess" seems to be a bit of an oxymoron to me because, to me, chess is not simple.  There are simpler games if you want to learn.  If you want to stick with chess, there is probably plenty of literature you could find about programming it if you choose to search.  My suggestion: try reading this [pgn example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation#Example) and [render the game move by move](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_of_the_Century_(chess)).  Use [unicode chess symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols).  Render to a console or a JavaFX app.

Comment: Here is a demo I created that shows how to drag and drop pieces. Hopefully, this can help. https://github.com/sedj601/ChessFX